# EXECUTE statement syntax error in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am working on an extension of a PostgreSQL library that takes a string representation of a query as input.  Basically I need to instantiate the resulting table that this string-based query produces, modify it, and then pass it to another function.

Right now I am just trying to get the query instatiated as a temporary table, so I am using this sample query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE pgr_table (seq INTEGER, path_seq INTEGER, node INTEGER, edge BIGINT, cost DOUBLE PRECISION, agg_cost DOUBLE PRECISION);

EXECUTE 'SELECT gid AS id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM ways;' INTO pgr_table;
```

But this results in a syntax error, just after the `EXECUTE` command.  Am I not using it correctly?

By the way, I am aware of the dangers of SQL injection and using `EXECUTE` willy-nilly.  The queries that I am making are not designed for front-end use, and I am following the design patterns already set forth by the library which I am modifying.

Comment: You can only use `execute` inside a PL/pgSQL function

Comment: you confuse SQL execute and plpgsql execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you confuse SQL execute and plpgsql execute - first to execute prepared statement and is run in SQL (as you try). second is a part of function plpgsql code

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-execute.html

> EXECUTE — execute a prepared statement

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

> Oftentimes you will want to generate dynamic commands inside your
>   PL/pgSQL functions, that is, commands that will involve different
>   tables or different data types each time they are executed. PL/pgSQL's
>   normal attempts to cache plans for commands (as discussed in Section
>   42.10.2) will not work in such scenarios. To handle this sort of problem, the EXECUTE statement is provided:

examples:

```
t=# prepare s as select now();
PREPARE
t=# execute s;
              now
-------------------------------
 2017-12-14 12:47:28.844485+00
(1 row)
```

and plpgsql:

```
t=# do
$$
declare
 t text;
begin
execute 'select now()' into t;
raise info '%',t;
end;
$$
;
INFO:  2017-12-14 12:48:45.902768+00
DO
```

**updtae**

to avoid injection using dynamic code, use function `format`
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

> Format arguments according to a format string. This function is
>   similar to the C function sprintf.